# Compilador acusando erro que não conheço

Tags: c, funções, random

```
#include<stdio.h>
int sumofDie(int value1, int value2);
int main( void ){
int die1[7];
int die2[7];
int i;

srand(time(NULL));

printf("Rolling die 1 ..........\n");

for( i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    int value;
    value = 1 + rand() % 6;
    die1[i] = value;
}

printf("Rolling die 2......\n");

for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    int value;
    value = 1 + rand() % 6;
    die2[i] = value;


}
for( i = 0; i < 6; i++){

    printf("The %d value of the array of the first die is: %d \n", i + 1, die1[i]);
    if ( i == 6){
        int k;
        printf("\n");
        for( k = 0; k < 6; k++){
            printf("The %d value of the array of the second die is: %d\n", k + 1, die2[k]);
        }

    }
}

sumofDie(die1,die2);

return 0;




}


int sumofDie( value1, value2){
int sum = 0;
int i;
for( i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    sum = value1[i] + value2[i];
    if ( i == 6){

        return sum;
    }
}



}
```

Provavelmente eu fiz de uma forma muito longa, mesmo havendo uma forma mais simples de se fazer, mas vamos lá: Fiz esse programa pra "capturar" os numeros aleatorios de dois dados de 6 lados e depois disso soma-los... tentei usar uma função no final pra praticar mais o que venho aprendendo até agora mas acontece que quando tento compilar, um erro que eu ainda não sei identificar aparece >> **expected 'int' but argument is of type 'int *'**  pesquisei em alguns lugares e vi algumas pessoas comentando sobre ponteiros, ainda não entrei nesse assunto em C e, se for esse mesmo o caso, como eu deveria fazer esse programa de modo que eu use fuma função para somar o valor final?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual a linha do erro? Geralmente os compiladores apontam... ou não ... faz tanto tempo que não mexo com C que nem lembro....

Comment: Não tem a ver com programação, mas dado em inglês é dice. Die é morrer. À propósito, vocês tem dado em casa?

Comment: Detalhe: Não causa problemas, mas você tem 7 posições nos seus dados, mas só usa 6.

Comment: Não é necessário indicar o tipo do vetor? tipo int sumofDie(int *value1, int *value2) ou então int sumofDie(int value1[], int value2[]) ou int sumofDie(int  value1[7], int value2[7])

Comment: complementarmente vários dos warnings são também erros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro acontece porque você passou `die1` e `die2` como parâmetros para a função `sumofDie`, e die1 e die2 são dois vetores (apontadores '*'); lembrando que a função recebe dois int's como parâmetros, `value1` e `value2`.

Comment: Outras coisas, você criou int die[7], um `vetor` de 7 posições (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6). Mas o seu for só percorre de i = 0, até i = 5. (6 posições)

Answer (score 2):

Sua função sumofDie(value1, value2) embora sempre vá chegar num momento que i vai ser igual a 6 (na última interação), acho que o compilador está implicando porque não tem nenhum return fora do loop, além do que seu return está dentro de um if, o que muitas vezes pode indicar um bloco inalcançável. Se ali fosse por exemplo if(i==7), nunca iria entrar naquele bloco, então sua função não teria nenhum retorno e na declaração da mesma diz que você deve retornar um inteiro.

Experimenta o seguinte, ao invés de:

```
int sumofDie( value1, value2){
int sum = 0;
int i;
for( i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    sum = value1[i] + value2[i];
    if ( i == 6){

        return sum;
    }
}



}
```

Escreva:

```
int sumofDie(int value1[], int value2[])
{
    int sum = 0;
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + value1[i] + value2[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Editado: Alterada a linha:

```
sum = value1[i] + value2[i];
```

para

```
sum = sum + value1[i] + value2[i];
```

Pois acredito que o que você queira é a soma de todas as jogadas, senão não teria sentido estar dentro do for.

Comment: adicionalmente parece-me que `for(...;i<6;...)` implica que nunca vai acontecer `i==6`

Answer (score 2):

Creio que o erro esta na declaração da função. Deveria ser algo do tipo:

```
int sumofDie(int *value1, int *value2)
```

ou então

```
int sumofDie(int value1[], int value2[])
```

ou

```
int sumofDie(int value1[7], int value2[7])
```

e tem a questão que o Antonio Alexandre postou.

Comment: +1 pra vc. Verdade, não lembrava mas em C tem que declarar o tipo dos parâmetros. Até editei na minha resposta tb.